# Swift/XCode - Why can't I pass data to the next view controller when a tableViewCell is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Apologies if this has already been answered elsewhere- I have spent the last two hours trying different things using similar suggestions but I still can't solve it!

Basically, I have a UITableView with custom cells(for different quiz topics) that when pressed, should allow the app to go to the next VC and pass an integer so the next VC knows which quiz to load.  In my table view VC I have this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    rowPressed = indexPath.row
    print ("rowPressed = \(rowPressed) before VC changes")

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.destination is GameVC {
        let vc = segue.destination as? GameVC
        vc?.toPass = rowPressed
        print("I ran...")
    } else {
        print("You suck")
    }
```

and in my GameVC I have this:

```
var toPass = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    print("toPass = \(toPass)")
```

The console output when run is this:

```
I ran...
toPass = 0
rowPressed = 3 before VC changes
```

So it looks like the VC changes before the previous one can send the correct value of toPass.  How do I fix this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Ryan But toPass is still 0 in viewDidAppear.  How do I get it to pass the correct toPass to the GameVC?

Comment: Thanks for your input.  So I call performSegue(withIdentifier: “toGameVC”, sender: Any?) having set the segue ID to toGameVC in storyboard view.  How do I then pass the toPass data? I have added the performSegue line to the didSelectRowAt function

Comment: First ensure `vc` is not an optional by using `guard` and then assign the value again. Otherwise your segue identifier can have a typo and your `vc` variable is nil.

Comment: Thanks Marc - not really sure what you mean though - could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested you have to call the performSegue method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // not necessary 
    //rowPressed = indexPath.row
    //print ("rowPressed = \(rowPressed) before VC changes")

    performSegueWithIdentifier("Your id", sender: indexPath)
    //You can set the identifier in the storyboard, by clicking on the segue
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Your id"{
        var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! GameVC
        vc.toPass = (sender as! IndexPath).row
    }
}
```

Comment: This did the trick thank you!  I control dragged from the yellow icon at the top of the first VC to the GameVC and then followed your instructions.  Thanks to everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3):

According to the segue description:

> For example, if the segue originated from a table view, the sender parameter would identify the table view cell that the user tapped.

So, sender is a `UITableViewCell` and you can do like below:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell else { return }
    guard let idx = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
    guard let vc = segue.destination as? GameVC else { return }
    vc.toPass = idx.row
}
```

The problem of your code was `prepare(segue:)` was invoked before `tableView(didSelectRowAt:)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `prepareForSegue` is called before `didSelectRowAt`, you can also remove the segue from the Storyboard, drag and drop holding ctrl from the `UITableViewController`'s yellow icon in the top to the second `ViewController`, click on the segue, give it an identifier, so now you can call `performSegue`:

```swift
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.pressed = indexPath.row
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue identifier", sender: nil)
}
```